# Resolve the partial differential equation on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $(\Delta-m^2)f=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Resolve the partial differential equation  on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $(\Delta-m^2)f=0$. The hint is use variable change, $f(r)=\frac{g(r)}{r}$ where $r=\sqrt{x_1^2 +x_2^2 +x_3^2}$.

When i did that, $\Delta f(r)=m^2f(r)$, so its look like a ordinary linear equation, so i try to expand the expression

$\Delta f(r)= \sum_{i=1}^3 \partial_{x_i}^2 f(r)$, but i have problem with the chain rule

$\partial_{x_i} f(r)= \frac{df(r)}{dr}\frac{\partial r}{\partial_{x_i}}= \frac{df(r)}{dr}\frac{x_i}{r} $, now i need to applicate again derivate, hence

$\partial_{x_i}^2 f(r)=\partial_{x_i} (\frac{df(r)}{dr}\frac{x_i}{r})= \frac{d^2f(r)}{dr^2}\frac{x_i^2}{r^2}+ \frac{df(r)}{dr}(\frac{r -x_i(\frac{x_i}{r})}{r^2})$ then

$\Delta f(r)= \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{d^2f(r)}{dr^2}\frac{x_i^2}{r^2}+ \frac{df(r)}{dr}(\frac{r^2-x_i^2}{r^3})=\frac{d^2f(r)}{dr^2} +\frac{2}{r}\frac{df(r)}{dr}$. Therefore

I need to resolve the equation $\frac{d^2f(r)}{dr^2} +\frac{2}{r}\frac{df(r)}{dr}-m^2f(r)=0$

Please can somebody help me to continued or perhaps i doing something wrong?
I can not to reduce the order of equation, i would like to know what method can use.

Thank you

Comment: (1) What do you mean by resolve? (2) From the context, it looks like you're only looking for radial solutions (i.e. $f$ only depends on $r$), is this the case?

Comment: Sorry by the confusion, exactly, i am looking the radial solution, but i am not sure how to continued, please if you can help me one hint, i will appreciate so much!

Comment: I'm not sure further hints could help you, I think that it would rather be best to refresh your memory of the $D(f \circ g)$ formula (aka the chain rule). Then the hint you have (i.e. compute $\Delta f$, where $f(x) = \overline{f}(r(x))$) should be enough.

Comment: Thank you dear Michal, i will try, but my count in the post is right?

Comment: This is wrong (or maybe just a typo): $\partial_{x_i} f(r)= \partial_{x_i}f(r)\frac{x_i}{r} $. The derivative on the RHS should be $\frac{df(r)}{dr}$

Comment: Thank you Dear Winther,

Comment: With your comments i have a new post, please what can i do with the $\sum_{i=1}^3x_i$, thank you

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dx}(x g(r)) = g(r) + x\frac{d}{dx}(g(r))$ and the latter term is $x\frac{d}{dx}(g(r)) = x\frac{dr}{dx}\frac{d}{dr}(g(r)) = \frac{x^2}{r}g'(r)$. Thus if you correct this you will end up with $\sum x_i^2$ instead which you can easily relate to $r$. You also have a mistake in the last term $2/r^3$ should be $2/r$. But its getting close to correct!

Comment: How to resolve the las equation in my post? I can to reduce your order, i do not how to resolve!!thank you

Comment: The Laplacian in spherical coordinates should be an Euler-type operator, no?

Comment: What is $(r f(r))''$ ? You can use this to simplify the equation down to something much more familiar.

Comment: Hi all, i do a new post, perhaps somebody can help me to find the solution for the ODE please? thank you all

Comment: It was a hint above: try to introduce $g(r) = r f(r)$ and the ODE for $g(r)$ will be much simpler (you get a homogenous second order equation which can be solved in the usual way https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus) )

Comment: Thank you dear Winther

Comment: I get it, thank you so much!!